# Css is not loading after changed the GetDbConnection() in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii Framwork, I have used the steps from [Multiple-database support in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/) to connect different database , its helped me lot.

but Css is not loaded, normal HTML content is displaying in browser when I'm opening the index.php

What changes is require to load the CSS after changing the GetDbConnection() in modules.

my Ad.php code from models

```
<?php

class Ad extends MyActiveRecord
{
    public $password;
    public $repassword;

    public function getDbConnection()
    {
        return self::getCCDbConnection();
    }


    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    ....

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's not cause of multiple database support. Css with MDB  
as like as chalk and cheese.

Comment: css and db have nothing in common as ineersa says; i will help you with the good code for multiple dbs in yii; pls wait, as i paste the code

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve your css problem, however, this is the right way to use multiple dbs in yii.

This is the right way to use `multiple db's` in `yii mvc`:

Let's say that i have multiple db's and I use them to store urls.

From time to time I need to change the db.

So, I have the model generated by using `gii` and on top of that I have class that extends and overwrites some of methods/functions.

`UrlSlaveM` extends `UrlSlave` wich extends `CActiveRecord`

as default, in `UrlSlave` I will connect to my first db

I always use `UrlSlaveM` when I insert new data, so that I can overwrite the following function:

public function getDbConnection() {
    return Yii::app()->db1;
}

here is a full `SlaveUrl` model:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "url".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'url':
 * @property string $id
 * @property integer $instance_id
 * @property integer $website_id
 * @property string $link
 * @property string $title
 * @property integer $created
 * @property integer $updated
 * @property integer $status
 */
class UrlSlave extends CActiveRecord {

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return UrlSlave the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return CDbConnection database connection
     */
    public function getDbConnection() {
        return Yii::app()->db1;
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName() {
        return 'url';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('instance_id, website_id, link, title, created, updated, status', 'required'),
            array('instance_id, website_id, created, updated, status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
            array('link, title', 'length', 'max' => 255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, instance_id, website_id, link, title, created, updated, status', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations() {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'instance_id' => 'Instance',
            'website_id' => 'Website',
            'link' => 'Link',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'created' => 'Created',
            'updated' => 'Updated',
            'status' => 'Status',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search() {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
        $criteria->compare('instance_id', $this->instance_id);
        $criteria->compare('website_id', $this->website_id);
        $criteria->compare('link', $this->link, true);
        $criteria->compare('title', $this->title, true);
        $criteria->compare('created', $this->created);
        $criteria->compare('updated', $this->updated);
        $criteria->compare('status', $this->status);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }

}
```

and here is the full `UrlSlaveM` model:

```
<?php

class UrlSlaveM extends UrlSlave {

    const ACTIVE = 1;
    const INACTIVE = 0;
    const BANNED = -1;

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function rules() {
        $parent_rules = parent::rules();
        $rules = array_merge(
                $parent_rules, array(
            array('link', 'unique'),
        ));
        return $rules;
    }

    public static $server_id = 1;
    public static $master_db;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        //echo __FUNCTION__;
        //die;
        //echo 111;
        self::$master_db = Yii::app()->{"db" . self::$server_id};
        if (self::$master_db instanceof CDbConnection) {
            self::$master_db->setActive(true);
            return self::$master_db;
        }
        else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }

}
```

now, by setting `$server_id` to 1 or 2 or 3 ... you are able to connect to another db

please set the value of `$server_id` as `UrlSlaveM::$server_id = 2;` before you add data!

```
public static $server_id = 1;
    public static $master_db;
```

also, in the main config file, set like this:

```
'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'db2' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => '',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
        ),
        'db1' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dvc1',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => '',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
        ),
```